# Seaborn pairplot hue parameter not working as expected

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

If "C" was assigned as value for the "hue" parameter, it was expected Seaborn not displayed column "C". Am I wrong?

```
sns.pairplot(df, hue='C')
```

[image]

DataFrame:

[image]

Comment: Can you share more details on your dataframe

Comment: When using `hue` you should use the `vars` argument as well. Else the result may not make too much sense, at least if the hue is set to a column with numeric values in it.

Comment: You're right, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Thanks!

Comment: Where can I get list of all acceptable values of hue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, seaborn will show all numeric columns!

So if your 'hue' column ('C' in your case) column as string(object) type, it will not be visible on the graph

For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {
    'A': [*np.random.random(5)],
    'B': [*np.random.random(5)],
    'C': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

```
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
sns.pairplot(df, hue='C')
```

[image]

However, if you have 'C' column as the numerical values, you have to use 'vars' to specify what columns you are going to use:

> [vars](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) : list of variable names, optional
>
> Variables within data to use, otherwise use every column with a
>   numeric datatype.

```
data = {
    'A': [*np.random.random(5)],
    'B': [*np.random.random(5)],
    'C': [*np.random.randint(1, 3, 5)]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

```
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
sns.pairplot(df, hue='C', vars=['A', 'B'])
```

[image]

Comment: sns.pairplot also seems to plot *boolean* valued columns by default.